# How to catch all errors from browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, watchify

I use the following gulp task

```
const gulp          = require('gulp');
const browserify    = require('browserify');
const watchify      = require('watchify');
const source        = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const gutil         = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('watchify', () => {

    var bundler = watchify(browserify('./test/app.js', {
            debug: true,
            fullPaths: true,
            paths: ['./src'],
            cache: {},
            packageCache: {}
        }))
    .on('update', bundle)
    .on('error', (error) => { gutil.log('[error]', error); });

    function bundle(){
        return bundler
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./test/'));
    }

    return bundle();

});
```

But today the browserify process hung without sending the error event, after hours of trail and error I found out it was because of something like this:

```
aFunction(argA, , argC);
```

(some work-in-progress code where I missed an argument in a function call)

***My question is, how can I listen to these kind of errors more easily?***

I could of course lint the files first but i'd also like to know if it's possible within browserify.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this](https://github.com/marcello3d/gulp-watchify/pull/4) unmerged pull request for `watchify` might have fixed your problem - it appears that errors don't get caught properly in the `gulp-watchify` module so you never get to see them.

You might have more success using the official [Gulp recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/fast-browserify-builds-with-watchify.md) for Browserify and Watchify which doesn't use the `gulp-watchify` module.

---

It appears that the issue is that Gulp is never informed of the error when it occurs. Try using this error handling code:

```
(error) => { 
    gutil.log('[error]', error); 
    this.emit('end');
}
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't write that, but I'm already using that recipe.

Comment: I've done a bit more research about it, and found another potential solution. Check my edited answer.